# How to clean apt cache using ansible?

Tags: ansible, apt

This [link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/compare/devel...tersmitten:support-apt-get-autoclean) hints at existence of a module but I am unable to implement it. Any solution is anticipated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using Ansible 2.13 or later, you can use [the `clean` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-clean):

```
- ansible.builtin.apt:
    clean: yes
  become: yes
```

In older versions, you can use [the `command` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html):

```
- command: apt-get clean
  become: yes
```